# how to get all the data from row of parse.com databrowser in android?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a class on parse.com named "MQOD" ,it is having several coloumns,I want to get DeviceId List and check it with my device it,And If that array contais my deviceId,I want to get all data from that row.My table in parse.com is as below,
[image: My class on parse]

I have tried as below,Which gives me size of array,But I dont know how to check in that array for my deviceId,and get that row's data.

**code**

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("MQOD");
        query.whereExists("DeviceId");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> ClientList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("DeviceId", "Retrieved " + ClientList.size()
                            + " DeviceId");
                    System.out
                            .println("::::::::::::::::::MY arrayList:::::::::::::from Parsde.::::::::::::::::"
                                    + ClientList.toString());
                    Log.d("Installation date", "Retrieved "
                            + ClientList.get(1).get("InstalationDate")
                            + " DeviceId");
                } else {
                    Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have got answer,I have changed my code as below,And I solved my Problem
**code**

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("MQOD");
        // query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
        query.whereEqualTo("DeviceId", android_id);
        // query.toString();
        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::QUERY:::::::::::::::" + query);
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (ob.size() > 0) {
            // IS INSTALLED ON DEVICE..!!!
            for (ParseObject mediObject : ob) {
                Const.DeviceId = mediObject.get("DeviceId").toString();
                Const.InstDate = mediObject.get("InstallationDate").toString();
                Const.UpDate = mediObject.get("NextSubscription").toString();

            }
}catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```